# Redireccionar de un dominio a otro y enmascarar

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirección

Tengo un dominio web (xxx.com) redireccionado con .htaccess al dominio web yyy.com y funciona correctamente, lo que necesito ahora es enmascarar la url, en resumidas cuentas que aparezca en el navegador la dirección xxx.com
La redirección la tengo de esta manera:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xxx\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.yyy\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

¿Se puede hacer?

Comment: Hay muchas variables a aclarar para poder dar una solución. ¿Los dos dominios están alojados  en el mismo servidor? ¿Tienes acceso a la configuracción del servidor? ¿La redirección la hiciste desde la configuración del DNS?

Comment: hola, los dominios están en distintos hosting, tengo acceso al cpanel en ambos dominios, la configuración la hice en el cpanel del dominio xxx.com o sea el que estoy redireccionando al dominio yyy.com

Comment: vas a tener que utilizas Alias en tu virtualhost