# Enmascarar URL tras redireccionamiento

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirección

llevo un buen tiempo buscando en el sitio la forma de hacer lo que quiero, lo más cercano es esto que encontré: [Redireccionar de un dominio a otro y enmascarar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/215403/redireccionar-de-un-dominio-a-otro-y-enmascarar)

Si situación es similar a la mía. Pongo un poco en contexto la situación, tengo dos dominios, ambos en diferentes servicios de hosting. Uno es empresarial y el otro personal.

Tengo un formulario de contacto para la web empresarial que no funciona en su hosting, ya comprobé que es una restricción del proveedor.

Ese mismo código funciona bien en mi hosting personal, por lo que quiero redirigir sólo esa página de contacto a mi dominio personal. Ya tengo esa parte, ahora lo que quiero es enmascarar esa URL, para que no se vea `personal.com/contacto` sino más bien `miempresa.com/contacto`.

Es esto posible? Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lo dudo muchísimo. La URL que se muestra es parte de la lógica del navegador, no es parte de HTTP ni de HTML. Y la tendencia es, por seguridad, impedir que se enmascaren las URLs (por ejemplo sacándote un mensaje enorme si la URL no coincide con el certificado). No tendría ningún sentido intentar hacer el navegador más seguro y luego dejarme que presente mi sitio privado como si fuera https://weboficialdemibanco.es tan ricamente...

Comment: Aparte de eso, la idea y la solución que propones hacen que me suenen varias alarmas... Te estarías metiendo en un terreno **MUY DELICADO**, al llevar datos de la empresa a tu servidor personal (y no quiero ni pensar si además fuera aplicable el GDPR).

Comment: solo una opinión: si web empresarial está restringido por proveedor para sus operaciones, debería cambiar de proveedor si no lo hace no es muy empresarial. Al fin y alcabo los proveedores son sólo recursos, sirven o no sirven.

Comment: Gracias por sus amables observaciones, entiendo el riesgo en cuanto a seguridad, pero sólo estoy haciendo un formulario de contacto, y sí, pienso lo mismo sobre el proveedor, no sé porque no se cambia, pero esas decisiones ya se salen de mi manejo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si en el servidor de empresa tienes curl, podrías redireccionar los datos, recibes el formulario de forma normal en miempresa.com/contacto, pero procesas cada $_POST y reenviarlo a personal.com/contactoOculto.

```
function send_post($url, $data){
$ch = curl_init();  // initialize curl handle 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url to post to 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILonerror, 1); //Fail on error
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // add POST fields
$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process 
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email= $_POST['email'];

$url = "personal.com/contactoOculto";
$post = "nombre=".$nombre."&email=".$email;
$envio = send_post($url, $post);
```

Comment: Me parece una opción viable. Perdón mi ignorancia, cómo sabría si usa o no CURL?

Comment: @Alvamon6 crea un php y pone **phpinfo();**, busca "curl", si aparece es por que está y podria funcionar :D